# jQuery Ajax PHP security

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, security

Is there any way to prevent jQuery AJAX retreiving a complete PHP file instead of its server output ?
I just tried  to obtain  text only  output,  expecting  what ever php decides  to return,  but got  the whole  file.
Not  ideal  if as on some files  it  would  reveal potential  hacking  targets such  as database  tables  etc

Comment: You mean a PHP source file? That should never happen, Ajax or not. If that happens for you, your server is badly misconfigured.

Comment: Does your PHP file have the `<?php` tag at the start. If not it *might* render as a normal HTML file (depending on your server configuration).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The host was not allowing config of private files, the solution was to move provider and place php above the root directory.